# Show ACF field value on edit order page WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, orders

I added some custom fields with ACF to my products.
Now I want to show one this fields on each ordered item on the edit order page after an order is placed.
So now each product that is bought is shown (product title) on the WooCommerce edit order page. In each item I want to show the custom field too. Does someone know a function for this?

Found something like this but this is for the whole order instead of each ordered item:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'optigem_sendungsnummer', 20);


    function optigem_sendungsnummer( $order ) {

    if (get_field('sendungsnummer', $order->id)) { // Only show if field is filled

?>
        <p class="sendungsnummer">DHL: <?php the_field('sendungsnummer', $order->id);    ?><p>          
        <?php 

    }

}
```

EDIT: found the solution here ;)
[Output a product custom field in WooCommerce Order Admin Page (ACF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001375/output-a-product-custom-field-in-woocommerce-order-admin-page-acf)

Comment: Also your question code is outdated and `$order->id` need to be `$order->get_id()`.